# How to Run chokidar in the background (persistent: true)?

Tags: node.js, npm, chokidar

I am writing a node.js program that needs to watch for (add/delete/update) files in a folder. I am using chokidar for watching the files. Here's the code

```
async function updateIndexFile() {
    console.log({ path });
    const pathArray = []

    // Chokidar Code
    const options = {
      ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../, // ignore dotfiles
      persistent: true
    }

    // Initialize watcher.
    const watcher = chokidar.watch(path, options);

    watcher
      .on('add', async (path) => {
        console.log(`File ${path} has been added`)
        let answer = await prompt({
          type: 'list',
          name: 'adventure',  // * Key
          message: 'Choose your own adventure',
          choices: ['Indexify', 'Undo'] // * Add Feature Names Here
        })
        console.log(answer);        
      })  // Run indexify again on these files
      .on('change', path => console.log(`File ${path} has been changed`)) // Run indexify again on these files
      .on('unlink', path => console.log(`File ${path} has been removed`));  // Run indexify again on these files
```

[image: But, with persistent: true. I]

But, I cant use the terminal as chokidar is watching the files. So, I want chokidar to watch files in the background. So, I can still prompt the user for more questions and do my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I know i am 3 months late , and you probably had found you answer by now, but this is for anyone who is visiting later.
You can use spawn child process using node module called.
simple put your code in a file and execute that file using below code

```
 const {spawn}=require(child_prcoess);
let detached_process = spawn(process.argv[0], ["program_name", "arg1","arg2","arg3"], { detached: true}); //launch program_name and detach it from program_name with args provided

            detached_process.unref(); //tell main program to do not wait for the completion of program_name
```